# Disable remote drives for RDS and RemoteApp users

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rds, remoteapp

How do I allow users to get to their local drives in Remote App but not see the Remote Server drives in RemoteApp?  I can see how I can disable Redirection for client local resources but not where I can restrict availability of server resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a Group Policy setting to hide drives under User Configuration|Administrative Templates|Windows Components|Windows Explorer.

Comment: Does this hide the client local drives as well?  I don't want to lose them.

Comment: Are these users accessing the RemoteApp from domain joined computers? If so, then assuming they log onto the domain joined computers with the same user account that they use to authenticate to the RemoteApp then you'll probably want to configure this setting in the GPO that applies to the RemoteApp servers and use loopback policy processing so that it will apply to them only when they use the RemoteApp.